# putting fixed content to flexslider slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I need a help with putting fixed content to flexslider. I mean, that there would be some text or some button and the slideshow will be like background to it. I was inspired by one topic here on stackoverflow and I did something like this.

```
<div class="flexslider">
                <div class="textinside">Some text</div>

                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="/images/1.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/images/2.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/images/3.jpg" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And style for .textinside:

```
 .textinside{ width:15%; background-color:black; padding:10px; text-align:center; }
 .textinside{ position:absolute; top:100px; left:50%; margin-left:-500px; z-index:1;}
```

The problem is that this text is shown just for a little moment when the slides are changing and then dissapears. Every flexslider options are set to default. Could be anyone so kind and help me fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `z-index` value:

```
.textinside {
    /* ... other styles */
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Flexslider `li` items has `z-index: 2`. Which explains why you see your text flashing for a short while during items transition. Make `.textinside` z-index at least 3.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly I needed. You saved me a huge couple of time. :)